# Controller Tests for Service Layer Logic

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I have a solution with the following architecture MVC app > Services > Repositories. Now lets say I have a Document Model and a Document has many Notes. I have a Notes controller with an AddNote(documentID) action. Now my business rules say that only the users associated with the document can add notes so I enforce this. I am currently going with the following method:

```
public ActionResult AddNote(int documentID)
    {
        try
        {
            NoteCreateEditViewModel viewModel = Mapper.Map<Note, NoteCreateEditViewModel>(noteService.GetNewNote(User.Identity, documentID));
            return View(viewModel);
        }
        catch (BusinessLogicException validationException)
        {
            // Send user somewhere else.
        }
    }
```

noteService.GetNewNote(User.Identity, documentID) throws a BusinessLogicException should the user have no right on the Document. I am using an exception as this seems to be the best way to handle business/validation violations (although I personally feel this is bad use of exceptions!).

When testing the above from a controller test, should I just be testing that the correct redirect (or whatever) happens should the BusinessLogicException be thrown or should I be simulating an unauthorised user/non existent documentID etc? In my mind, the service test for GetNewNote(User.Identity, documentID) would be the place to simulate an unauthorised user as this ensures my tests are testing the core functionality of a particular piece of code.

However, if I dont write a controller test which simulates an unauthorised user generating an Exception, then how will someone who looks at my tests in the future understand that the desired functionality of AddNote is to prevent unauthorised users from adding notes. If they dont understand this they may be tempted to simply initialise a new Note directly in the controller, rather than through noteService.GetNewNote(User.Identity, documentID).

So should I be testing more in my controllers or is there a much simpler design in adding associated models?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your unit test you should mock the `noteService.GetNewNote` method call so that it throws a `BusinessLogicException`. Then assert that the controller action returned a redirect result.

Comment: But then my controller test won't make it explicit that a user must have access to the specified Document. So anyone who maintains the application in the future wont realise the importance of creating a new note through the service over creating a new note directly in the controller - no tests will break if they make this change but required business logic is bypassed.

Comment: Maybe I am just overthinking things. The fact that the noteService.GetNewNote method is mocked in the controller test should alert other developers to the need for the service layer to create Notes. But doesnt ensure that the method is actually called. Is there a way to do this, to test a method is called with MSTest?

Comment: I am definitely overthinking this! The asserts are checking that an exception is thrown. If another dev avoids the call to noteService.GetNewNote then the exception won't occur and the test fails, forcing them to investigate futher and understand the process. Phew! This question has pretty much turned into a monologue but I got there in the end. Thanks Darin.